# Mikrotik 750G configuration backup

Tags: backup, router, mikrotik

I have two Mikrotik RouterBoard 750G device.
I would use the another as a cold backup replacement of the active one. 
But if I upload the configuration to the backup router I lose control above it, because the configuration doesn't recognize the new interfaces, and there's no serial interface to associate them.

Does anyone face this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use script to transfer configuration.

```
/export file=config.rsc
```

Transfer script to PC.

Fix script by removing mac-address options from interfaces at begining of script.

Transfer to other Mikrotik

And apply script.

```
/system reset-configuration no-defaults=yes run-after-reset=config.rsc
```

PS. For successful applying configuration new router must have enabled all packages which configuration exported.

Export file can be edited to cover some special cases (I know, user-manager configuration don't cleared by /system reset-configuration)